# Passing all data properly and still highcharts throwing error

Tags: highcharts

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

does anyone know y this error keeps appearing. Initially graph was working fine but suddenly it started showing this error and below that error i am seeing this error:

"ERROR TypeError: Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined"

Please let me know how to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance

Please find image attached
[image]

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, Please reproduce that error in some online code editor. You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek if i reproduce it in jsfiddle its working properly with single array of data. But i am creating multiple graphs and  displaying those graphs in carousel. I cant reproduce that carousel graph in jsfiddle. Please let me know whats the actual reason for such error. Initially it was working find for few months. suddenly it started throwing error.

Comment: That error may be caused by many things. You need to reproduce that situation if you want someone to help you. You can use some mockup data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. Array which is used for series has an undefined value in it then error appears. pass null or 0 instead of undefined and graphs works properly.